# ¿Cual puede ser, en este script, la causa del Type error?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader  as pdr
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime, date 

start = "2016-1-4"
end = date.today()
dic_tickers = {"Iberdrola":"IBE.MC", "Renta_4":"R4.MC", "Telefonica":"TEF.MC", 
           "Ibex_35":"^IBEX"}
    
tickers = ["IBE.MC", "R4.MC", "TEF.MC", "^IBEX"]

# Importar cotizaciones
def get(tickers, start, end):
    def data(ticker):
        return pdr.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
    datas = map(data, tickers)
    return pd.concat(datas, keys=tickers, names=['Ticker','Date']) 
all_data = get(tickers, start, end)

# reset the index to make everything columns
all_data = all_data[['Adj Close']].reset_index()
#df_analisis[:5]

""" We moved the dates into a column because we now want to pivot Date into the 
index and each Ticker value into a column:
"""
#daily_close_px = df_analisis.pivot('Date', 'Ticker', 'Adj Close')daily_close_px = df_analisis.pivot('Date', 'Ticker', 'Adj Close')   
df_analisis = all_data.pivot_table(values = "Adj Close", index = "Date", columns = "Ticker")
#daily_close_px[:3] 

# Ponderación de la inversión en cada activo 
def pondera_valores():
    # Calculamos el porcentaje de cada valor en la cartera seleccionada (lista_nombres)
    dicc_part = {"IBE.MC":49.328, "R4.MC":4496.57615, "TEF.MC":1193.86874,
                 "^IBEX":7260.63266}
    weights = []
    valor_actual_cartera = []
    Total = 0
    
    lista_nombres = dicc_part.keys()
    #for i in range (0, len(lista_nombres)):
    for items in lista_nombres:    
        ult_cotiz = df_analisis[lista_nombres[items]].iloc[-1]
        valor = ult_cotiz * dicc_part[lista_nombres[items]]
        valor_actual_cartera.append(valor)
        Total += valor

    for m in range (0, len(valor_actual_cartera)):    
        weights.append(round((valor_actual_cartera[m] / Total),2))

    print ("\nPesos ponderados de la cartera :", weights )
    print ("\nValor actual de la inversión en la cartera seleccionada :\n", round(Total,2), " €")
    print (valor_actual_cartera)
    
    weights = np.array(weights)
    return weights , Total, valor_actual_cartera

weights , Total, valor_actual_cartera  = pondera_valores()
```

No cabo de encontrar la causa del error que me devuelve este script:

```
TypeError: 'dict_keys' object is not subscriptable
```

Agradeceré ayuda.

Aunque sigo sin entender por qué se produce el error, he solucionando el problema iterando directamente sobre el diccionario.

```
for item in dicc_part.keys():    
        ult_cotiz = df_analisis[item].iloc[-1]
        valor = ult_cotiz * dicc_part[item]
        valor_actual_cartera.append(valor)
        Total += valor
```

Comment: parece ser un error en las librerías, el error no esta en tu script ya que ni siquiera aparece la variable 'dict_keys', podria ser la version de python que estas usando. chequea esta publicacion https://programmersought.com/article/51031393417/

Comment: Lo he solucionado iterando directamente sobre el diccionario.

Comment: super, podrías editar tu pregunta y poner el código de como lo solucionaste? para que en el futuro alguien lo vea.
saludos